# Python/Flask beginner: how to format db values?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm building a webapp with rankings for tennis club to learn python. Did start with a tutorial that was supposed to make a blog using python and flask. If neccessary you can find it here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3

So far I created a sqlite db called main.db, imported an excel sheet using seperate script and pandas as a table called playerslist into it with 3 columns: Name, Points, Active.

I have an app.py that queries all entries in the database and returns an index.html with all entries in the list. The points shows up as float value, with xxx.0 at the end. I would like to see integer instead but could not figure out how to 'format' each entry of one column when iterating rows.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '********************'

def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/main.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

...

@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    rows = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM playerslist').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', rows=rows)
```

index.html looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block title %} Tennis Rankings {% endblock %}</h1>
    {% for row in rows %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('data', Name=row['Name']) }}">
            <h2>{{ row['Name'] }}</h2>
        </a>
        <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ row['Points'] }}</span>
        <a href="{{ url_for('edit', Name=row['Name']) }}">
            <span class="badge badge-warning">Edit</span>
        </a>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I guess I either have to do this when querying the db or have to convert the db entries before querying it?! thanks in regards for helping out :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I figured out that with CAST you can do this. I changed

```
rows = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM playerslist').fetchall()
```

to

```
rows = conn.execute('SELECT Name, CAST (Points AS Int) as Points, Active FROM playerslist').fetchall()
```

I tried that before but I did not define 'as Points' after the CAST and got blank output on the index page because I figured out in one of those SQL "try--yourself" forms that if you do not redefine the Cast the first (index)row is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Query cannot be relied upon to return numbers in our preferred format, changing the DB will not really help you.

The only Easy Way out is to typecast it explicitly,

```
for row in rows:

 row = int(row)
```

Comment: That was my very first idea but in one row are multiple types of data so converting everything, even text, to integer is not the way